# Swift Autocomplete Username and Password

Tags: swift, keychain

I've seen iOS apps that can autofill username and passwords, even after you delete the app.  What is this technology called?  Is it storing the user name and password in the keychain?  I believe SnapChat works this way

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can store username and password in keychain, it will persist after delete and re-instal the app.

Comment: So the premise would be to store the username and password in the keychain, and every time you need to log in, check the keychain and give the option of auto-filling the credentials?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @ DJ_1990 Thanks

Comment: WWDC Video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206/

Comment: __keychain__ or __iCloud__.